# Can one user revert another user's default CL changes in a shared Perforce workarea?

Tags: perforce

Rev. P4/LINUX26X86_64/2011.1/393975 (2011/12/16).

I have a P4 workarea, created by user 1, that is intended to be shared by multiple users.  User 2 puts files on the opened default changelist, then abandons the workarea.  User 3 comes in and wants to wipe out those changes.  "p4 revert ..." fails because it says these opens belong to user 2.  The opened file has group rw privs, and user 3 is in that group, so I don't think it's a linux barrier.

It should almost go without saying that none of these users has any sort of system or admin privs.

Is there a way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2):

Perforce workspaces are not meant to be shared by multiple users.  Each user should have their own workspace (that all map the same depot files, e.g. a shared development branch) and submit their changes when they're ready to share them with the other users.

With `super` permissions in Perforce you can assume another user's identity and use that to revert a file that they've opened, but users with ordinary `write` permissions aren't able to mess with other users' work in progress.  Again: the idea is that each user should have their own workspace.

To summarize, the easiest solution to this problem is to make sure that each user has their own workspace rather than trying to share a single workspace.